# mysql if then else update procedure

Tags: mysql, if-statement

i want upgrade statement in procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `update` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `update`
     (IN mobile VARCHAR(20), IN registered BOOLEAN, IN charge BOOLEAN, IN debit_mon INT)
BEGIN
 DECLARE chargeTime Datetime;
 DECLARE lastdayNow Integer;
 DECLARE lastdayNext Integer;

 SET lastdayNow =  DAY(now());
 SET lastdayNext =  DAY(LAST_DAY(now() + interval 1 month));

 IF lastdayNow > lastdayNext then
   SET chargeTime = LAST_DAY(now() + interval 1 month);
 ELSE
   SET chargeTime = now() + interval 1 month;
 END IF;

 UPDATE `chat_acc` SET
     `registered` = registered,
     `charge` = charge,
     `debit_mon` = debit_mon,
     CHARGE_TIME = chargeTime 
   WHERE `phone` =mobile;
END $$
```

i want add case check field `source`:

```
if  source = 'A' or source = 'B' then set Charge Time = now() + interval 1 week
```

Thank any your help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the field name is `source`.
Try to add this in your stored procedures:

```
IF [source] = 'A' OR [source] = 'B' then
  SET chargeTime = now() + interval 1 week
END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing here, but if `source` is a column in `chat_acc` you can do something like this in your `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE `chat_acc` SET
   `registered` = registered,
   `charge` = charge,
   `debit_mon` = debit_mon,
   CHARGE_TIME =
      CASE WHEN chat_acc.source IN ('A', 'B') THEN now() + interval 1 week
      ELSE chargeTime
      END
WHERE `phone` =mobile;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I had upgrade successful